# Query with three conditions

Tags: mysql

I need to make query that will select all names and all nicknames from some table but only where id is in some array.This is The query:

```
SELECT n. * FROM nikovi n 
INNER JOIN sajt_nikovi s ON n.id = s.nik
WHERE s.sajt = '50' and     n.nadimak like '%ana%' or n.ime like '%ana%'
```

And it found all entries from table where n.ime like '%ana%', not only those for this join. does anyone have any idea?

Comment: use brackets to make a proper run of your query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AND binds harder than OR, which means that that it will evaluate something like;

```
WHERE (s.sajt = '50' and n.nadimak like '%ana%') or n.ime like '%ana%'
```

If you mean something else, you need to add parenthesis to make it clear to the database. In this case, you will need to change it to;

```
WHERE s.sajt = '50' and (n.nadimak like '%ana%' or n.ime like '%ana%')
```

Comment: you are faster than me,i am just writing the same answer and you hit the post..:-)

Answer (score 1):

Group your `OR`:

```
SELECT n. * 
FROM nikovi n 
INNER JOIN sajt_nikovi s 
ON n.id = s.nik 
WHERE s.sajt = '50' 
AND (n.nadimak LIKE '%ana%' OR n.ime LIKE '%ana%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use brackets, when you mix AND and OR

```
SELECT n. * FROM nikovi n INNER JOIN sajt_nikovi s ON n.id = s.nik WHERE s.sajt = '50' AND (n.nadimak LIKE '%ana%' OR n.ime LIKE '%ana%')
```